# How to create an time series in R for the .data format?

Tags: r, time-series, pivot-table, data-wrangling, noaa

I´m having some difficulties to read and create an time series objects in R for this datasets:

SOI: https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/soi.data
ONI: https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/oni.data

By seen the data we have in the first column the years and in the cols the months (Jan to Dec)

I expect to have something like this for SOI in R:

```
YearMonth  SOI
  <mth>    <dbl>
Jan 1948   -99.99
Feb 1948   -99.99
...         ...
Sep 2021   -1.3
Oct 2021   -99.99
Nov 2021   -99.99
Dec 2021   -99.99
```

And in the same way for ONI:

```
YearMonth  ONI
  <mth>    <dbl>
Jan 1950   -1.53
Feb 1950   -1.34
...         ...
Aug 2021   -0.46
Sep 2021   -99.90
Oct 2021   -99.90
Nov 2021   -99.90
Dec 2021   -99.90
```

I believe that the arrangement of this dataset may be the source of my difficulty, as I am not being able to correctly pivot this data.

I know that here in the stack we have good R users that will definitely help me with the best practice.

Comment: why don't you get the data directly from http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/oni.ascii.txt, which is from the [Sea Surface Temperatures (SSTs): Monthly Atmospheric & Sea Surface Temperature Indices](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/). Also rnoaa might help you if you have a api key from NOAA.

Comment: Thanks a lot @phiver ! This dataset is much easyer to extract the data! I´ll gonna see this package too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function seems to work for the two links shared but if there are more standard ways to get the data you can use that since they'll be more reliable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

read_data <- function(link) {
  read.table(link, skip = 1, fill = TRUE) %>%
    slice(-(grep('-99.9', V1):n())) %>%
    mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -V1) %>%
    mutate(name = month.abb[match(name, unique(name))]) %>%
    unite(YearMonth, V1, name, sep = ' ')
}

d1 <- read_data('https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/soi.data')
d1

# A tibble: 888 x 2
#  YearMonth value
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 1948 Jan  -100.
# 2 1948 Feb  -100.
# 3 1948 Mar  -100.
# 4 1948 Apr  -100.
# 5 1948 May  -100.
# 6 1948 Jun  -100.
# 7 1948 Jul  -100.
# 8 1948 Aug  -100.
# 9 1948 Sep  -100.
#10 1948 Oct  -100.
# … with 878 more rows
```

For the second link -

```
d2 <- read_data('https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/oni.data')
d2
# A tibble: 864 x 2
#   YearMonth value
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 1950 Jan  -1.53
# 2 1950 Feb  -1.34
# 3 1950 Mar  -1.16
# 4 1950 Apr  -1.18
# 5 1950 May  -1.07
# 6 1950 Jun  -0.85
# 7 1950 Jul  -0.54
# 8 1950 Aug  -0.42
# 9 1950 Sep  -0.39
#10 1950 Oct  -0.44
# … with 854 more rows
```